# capture the string next to known string using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long string. How can I find a string next to the known string.

example: '.lot of text..."number":"**999.999.9999**","make_model":"**device name**"....lot of text.'.

I know this value "999.999.9999". Using this as a sub string how do I capture "device name" and pass it as an alert/console.log? The device name is not a constant length.

Thanks

Comment: You can't, if you don't know the length, or what comes after it, you only have a starting point with no end point, and can't get the string you want

Comment: What is at each end of the string? Looks like it could be JSON

Comment: Is this JSON? If it is, there are way easier ways to accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Also, this looks like it might be JSON data. If you can, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the string to a Javascript Object. If it's not JSON though, your best bet is a regular expression.

Comment: i need to capture "device name" everything between the quotes.
although it is JSON. this is too complicated and dynamic to parase trough it

Comment: Why exactly is it too complicated? I'm assuming you have a an array of objects and you want to find an object in the array that has the number `999.999.9999` and then from that object you want to select the make_model?

Comment: Like the other commenters say, this really looks like JSON, so processing it as a string seems like the wrong approach. Parse it and loop through the object looking for the properties you want.

Comment: But if you're going to do it as a string, a regular expression seems like the simplest way to parse it.

Comment: the JSON has too many nested object with in nested objects and all of them are dynamic. so to phase through it i need to run many for loop and if condition for each of the object i encounter to find the key value pair i am looking for. so using string is a simpler option.
the answer below work. but how do i use regular exp to do the same assuming only the device name changes for different users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this if you are sure the number is only repeated once and length is always the same and make_model is always next to it.
basically it finds index of number and adds the length of number plus make_model ("999.999.9999","make_model":") which is 29 characters. and then we get the rest of string after this until we reach a double quotation and thats the end of make_model and what you want.

```js
var str = '.lot of text..."number":"999.999.9999","make_model":"device name"....lot of text.';
var chop = str.substr(str.indexOf('"999.999.9999"') + 29);
chop = chop.substring(0,chop.indexOf('"'));
console.log(chop);
```

Comment: This solution works but i would like to know how? what does +29 signify. is it for removing everything before "device name" and does this line chop.substring(0,chop.indexOf('"')); get the string between the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward answer is using `JSON.parse()`

```js
/* surround string with braces { <your string> } */
var input_str = '{' + '"foo":"bar","number":"999.999.9999","make_model":"some model name","device name":"some dummy device","name":"Arvind","profile":"freelancer"' + '}';

var json = JSON.parse(input_str);
console.log(json['device name']);
```